# Flashdevelop - class not found

Tags: flashdevelop, haxe

I struggled a problem :

In flashdevelop in source folder I created folder named Sprites and class Player.hx in it.

like this :

```
    package Sprites;
    class Player
    {
        public function new() { }
    }
```

Now i want to create instance in other class. I added right package import like this :

```
import Sprites.Player;
```

Everything seems ok, but i still get error :

```
source/Main.hx:2: characters 7-14 : Class not found : Sprites
```

Its weird because it tells me that Sprites is class but it isnt.

Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 1):

Okay i found sollution by myself. And post it here for everyone.

So i found that your subfolder in folder source cannot start with capital letter. Its weird, never seen this before but thats it.

I renamed Sprites for sprites and its working now.

Comment: It actually is wrong. Folder names can start with capital letters. It's packages that can't start with capital letter. And I'd recommend you to read language introduction before starting to write code - it's only a few pages.